# run script from npm package

Tags: javascript, npm

Say I have a function like so

**index.js**

```
sayHi = () => {
  console.log('hi');
}

sayHi();
```

and I want this to run immediately when the page loads so I call it with `sayHi();` now obviously this works when I have the file imported in my `index.html`

**index.html**

```html
<! -- ... -->
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

now I want to create this as a package other people can use so I have published it to npm and I can now install it using

```sh
npm install say-hi
```

How does `sayHi()` run from the users side?

I'm not exactly sure how to put this but basically once the user has installed the package using npm, I would like the script to run automatically. Is this possible?

Now I am aware that I could export the sayHi function and the user could import it and call it, I'm just wondering if this is the only way?

Comment: I assume that there is a (or several) question(s) behind this. What is it, that you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to distribute your code via npm? When should the function run? Where should it run: in the browser as soon as the page opens? What does "automatically" mean - this implies that it runs maybe "uncontrolled" or "unintentional" or do you mean "unattended". To me there are some questionmarks left before I could help.

Comment: @ThomasJunk basically I want to create an npm package that once installed basically installs some global listeners on the document and window - so to answer your questions 1. create global listeneres on the document and window. 2. the browser as soon as the page opens 3. automatically means without the user having to import the scripts into there index.html or call a function from a js file

Comment: @ThomasJunk for example this package https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar I just run npm install and it basically works straight away.. I dont have to do anything - this is similar to what I want to do

Comment: AFAIK is there no way to _just_ install a package and let the code run without importing said library. If you use a script tag the code is executed as soon as it is loaded. This is due to the implementation of how browsers execute javascript. But in terms of running a bundled version there has to be something which tells the bundler to include said code in the bundle, which is done via `require` or `import`. `export` is only necessary if you want to expose code externally to your file. But the question is: Do you need an npm-package for what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

You can add lifecycle handler scripts to package.json.  install or postinstall look like good candidates for your scenario

```
{
"scripts" :
  { "install" : "scripts/install.js"
  , "postinstall" : "scripts/install.js"
  }
}
```

More info at https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Answer (score 0):

`now my question is how does sayHi() run from the users side??
I'm not exactly sure how to put this but basically once the user has installed the package using npm, I would like the script to run automatically.. is this possible?`

If you publish your code as a package as you said, for users, a general usage or practise of your package is they `import` or `require` your package like `require('say-hi')`, at this moment (`require`), from your code, your sayHi() can be called immediately and you can see 'hi' in the console.

BTW, you do not really need to export anything if you do not want.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without requiring say hi?

Comment: for example this package https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar i just run npm install and then it works straight away I dont have to import anything

Comment: I do not know very much what you said `works straight away` and how it appears. I guess you need `postinstall` as testpossessed mentioned? Which means after users use `npm install xxx`, another script can be executed automatically after the installation. See the link he post and search `postinstall` https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts.

Comment: yeah I'm not entirely sure how to describe it, but I've checked `simplebar` package.json and they do not have a `postinstall` script so it must be able to be done some other way..

Comment: Yes. I now checked its package and did not see `postinstall`. BUT, I also did not see the effect that you said `works straight away` after run `npm install simplebar`. What did it look like after you run `npm install simplebar`?